# Why does deparse return a vector of length two here?

Tags: r, parsing

I need to deparse within R using `deparse(...)` which in all cases returned a vector of length one. But for the following I get a vector of length two:

```
> deparse(factor(All_cause_death, levels= c('Dead', 'Alive')) ~ Age_in_years + Systolic_Blood_pressure, backtick= TRUE)

[1] "factor(All_cause_death, levels = c(\"Dead\", \"Alive\")) ~ Age_in_years + "
[2] "    Systolic_Blood_pressure"
```

If I shorten the first variable name a bit I indeed get the expected output of length one:

```
> deparse(factor(Death, levels= c('Dead', 'Alive')) ~ Age_in_years + Systolic_Blood_pressure, backtick= TRUE)
[1] "factor(Death, levels = c(\"Dead\", \"Alive\")) ~ Age_in_years + Systolic_Blood_pressure"
```

In the code above I shortened the input by 10 elements by changing "All_cause_death" to "Death". Interestingly, if I shorten the input by 10 elements (or more) at the end of the input I do not get vector of length one:

```
> deparse(factor(All_cause_death, levels= c('Dead', 'Alive')) ~ Age_in_years + Systolic_, backtick= TRUE)
[1] "factor(All_cause_death, levels = c(\"Dead\", \"Alive\")) ~ Age_in_years + "
[2] "    Systolic_"
```

Why is this happening and how can I get a vector of length one for the first code?

Comment: You could easily get a length one vector by wrapping the `deparse` with paste: `paste(deparse([statement to be deparsed]), collapse = " ")`

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks, that is what I am doing at this point but I am still wondering why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: You could also use the `width.cutoff` argument in the `deparse()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deparse` will break across lines if they are longer than 60 characters. It has the `width.cutoff` parameter which you can set to a longer length if you prefer this not to happen:

```r
deparse(factor(All_cause_death, levels= c('Dead', 'Alive')) ~ Age_in_years+ Systolic_Blood_pressure, backtick= TRUE, width.cutoff = 200)
#> [1] "factor(All_cause_death, levels = c(\"Dead\", \"Alive\")) ~ Age_in_years + Systolic_Blood_pressure"
```

From the `deparse` documentation:

> `width.cutoff`
> integer in [20, 500] determining the cutoff (in bytes) at which line-breaking is tried.

You can use also use `deparse1` instead of `deparse`, which effectively just sets the maximum `width.cutoff` to 500 by default

```r
deparse1(factor(All_cause_death, levels= c('Dead', 'Alive')) ~ Age_in_years+ Systolic_Blood_pressure, backtick= TRUE)
#> [1] "factor(All_cause_death, levels = c(\"Dead\", \"Alive\")) ~ Age_in_years + Systolic_Blood_pressure"
```

From the documentation for `deparse1`:

> deparse1() is a simple utility added in R 4.0.0 to ensure a string result (character vector of length one), typically used in name construction, as deparse1(substitute(.)).